# CSV file to string

Tags: swift, runtime-error

I am trying to turn a CSV file into a string to parse it and am getting very confused by the errors. The code I am using is this:

```
let filename = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BaseballSimStats", ofType: "CSV")
var text = String()
do {
    text = try String(contentsOfFile: filename!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
} catch {
     print("File Read Error for file \(filename!)")
}
print(text)
```

I am getting an error saying that the execution was interrupted because a bad instruction and that it was unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. This made sense because I am using `filename!` but when I change it to a `?` I get the following error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: MyPlayground.playground:1:47: error: value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
text = try String(contentsOfFile: filename?, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                                          ^
                                  (        )!
```

This is telling me to fix it by adding the `!`, but I get the previous error when I do that. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `filename` is `nil` which means you have no such file in your app's bundle.

Comment: other than that it is fine? because there is a file called `BaseballSimStats.csv` in the bundle

Comment: `BaseballSimStats.csv` is not the same as `BaseballSimStats.CSV`. Case matters. And you should safely unwrap `filename`. Avoid using `!`.

Comment: But when I don't use it, it tells me to use it.

Comment: That's why you need to safely unwrap it. Read the duplicate and its answers I linked. And read all about optionals in the Swift book.

Comment: I'm understanding the mistake, `filename` is returning nil. Any ideas why?

Comment: I told you why in my very first comment.

Comment: Would it make a difference if it is in a playground inside my file?

Comment: You should use `Bundle.main.url(forResource: ..., withExtension: ...)`